# Hybrid remote and non-remote form under Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, jquery

In my application I have a form which has two submits: one is a typical submit button which creates an object and redirects the user to it. The other is intended to act as a "Save and Continue" button which creates the object remotely, displays a success flash, and clears the form without sending the user to a different page.

How might this be implemented? I am roughly familiar with AJAX with jQuery and have a few other forms making use of it across the site, but I cannot find a way to create a hybrid form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MurifoX's answer was on the right path. Here's something like what I did:

```
  if @model.save
    if params[:commit] == "Save"
      render js: %(window.location.pathname='#{object_path @object}')
    elsif params[:commit] == "Save and Continue"
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js do
          @object = Object.new
          render 'new'
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Basically, the form has remote set to true to respond properly to AJAX requests (jQuery.ajaxSetup({
        'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")} is also used). If "Save" is clicked, the browser is redirected via JavaScript to the appropriate page. If "Save and Continue" is clicked, the same _partial.js.erb that is used to load the form to begin with is AJAX'd in again with a new object to clear the form. In the actual code, I also do a flash to show that the new object has been created.

Answer (score 1):

Not a pretty approach but this works. On your `create` action in your controller, when you finish saving a record you can put some conditional logic to achieve different redirections like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @model.save
    if params[:commit] == "Save"
      # Redirect to saved object
    elsif params[:commit] == "Save and Continue"
      # Redirect to other places
    end
  end
end
```

The `params[:commit]` stores the string of your submit button, so you can use it to build a hybrid form.